# Not getting ORA-25156 "old style outer join (+) cannot be used with ANSI join" when I should be

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

When converting some old-style joins to the SQL-92 style a `(+)` was accidentally left in the query. No error was raised when I expected the error *ORA-25156: old style outer join (+) cannot be used with ANSI joins* to be raised.

I have the following tables:

```
create table inner_join ( 
   id integer
 , some_data varchar2(32)
   );

insert into inner_join values (1, 'a');
insert into inner_join values (2, 'b');

create table outer_join ( 
   id integer
 , some_data varchar2(32)
   );

insert into outer_join values(2, 'c');
insert into outer_join values(3, 'd');
```

A (more complicated) query like the following was being converted

```
select *
  from outer_join oj
     , inner_join ij
 where ij.id = oj.id(+);
```

and by mistake the query was converted as follows

```
select *
  from outer_join oj
  join inner_join ij
    on ij.id = oj.id(+);
```

This produces the expected results, however, it's quite dangerous because:

- It's easy for someone to assume that an INNER JOIN as opposed to an OUTER JOIN was intended (guess what happened...) thereby causing unintended errors when the query is changed again
- The exhibited behaviour might change in the future, resulting in errors in a number of places
- It seems to [contradict the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm#SQLRF52354)

  > You cannot specify the (+) operator in a query block that also contains FROM clause join syntax.
- A significant benefit of using the SQL-92 standard is that when there is an error in code (i.e. a missing join condition) there will be an error

I would always like ORA-25156 to be raised when it should be.

To demonstrate the issue: I do not get an error when I should if I run these queries

```
select *
  from outer_join oj
  join inner_join ij
    on ij.id = oj.id(+);

 ID SOME_DATA  ID SOME_DATA
--- --------- --- ---------
  2 c           2 b
                1 a


select *
  from inner_join ij
  join outer_join oj
    on ij.id = oj.id(+);

 ID SOME_DATA  ID SOME_DATA
--- --------- --- ---------
  2 b           2 c
  1 a
```

If I add a third table

```
create table middle_join ( 
   id integer
 , some_data varchar2(32)
   );

insert into middle_join values (1, 'e');
insert into middle_join values (2, 'f');
insert into middle_join values (3, 'g');
```

then when the old-style join is in the "middle" of the query there is no error

```
select *
  from inner_join ij
  join outer_join oj
    on ij.id = oj.id(+)
  join middle_join mj
    on ij.id = mj.id;

 ID SOME_DATA  ID SOME_DATA  ID SOME_DATA
--- --------- --- --------- --- ---------
  1 a                         1 e
  2 b           2 c           2 f
```

If the join is at the "end" of the query then the correct error(!) is raised.

```
select *
  from inner_join ij
  join middle_join mj
    on ij.id = mj.id
  join outer_join oj
    on ij.id = oj.id(+);
    on ij.id = oj.id(+)
               *
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-25156: old style outer join (+) cannot be used with ANSI joins
```

Why is this happening? How can I ensure that ORA-25156 is raised in all cases to avoid easy mistakes and future issues?

I've tested this on 12.1.0.1, but I'd be surprised if it's specific to this version...

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Oracle did lift some restrictions on the ancient and outdated outer join syntax with 12c: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NEWFT/chapter12101.htm#FEATURENO10371

Comment: The last join clause compares `oj.id` with itself (twice) instead of `ij.id` resp. `mj.id`, can you correct that and check if something changes?

Comment: Thanks @ammoQ; there were never going to be changes, but I've corrected the error.

Comment: Check it again... still something odd ;-)

Comment: I ran it in SQL*Plus, which is why the join condition looks duplicated, I can't see any specific differences as compared to the previous query @ammo.  I can replicate the error given any combination of 3 tables/sub-queries so the exact formulation isn't that important.

Comment: That doesn't appear to say that the restriction on mixing syntaxes has been lifted does it @a_horse? The docs linked on outer joins in there also suggest that one or the other is okay, but not both: _use the LEFT [OUTER] JOIN syntax in the FROM clause, or apply the outer join operator (+)_ and _You cannot specify the (+) operator in a query block that also contains FROM clause join syntax._

Comment: Regarding your very last comment (about Oracle version) - it is in fact possible that this bug (if indeed it's a bug, and it looks like it is) was introduced in 12.1, while they were making the changes discussed in the link provided by @a_horse. It would be nice if someone with an older version could run your tests to confirm one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error is raised when you try to use (+) in WHERE clause in ANSI Syntax query. There is no error when you try to do it in ON clause because in Oracle's old crappy syntax the ON clause was non-existent.

I guess it's messy that you can pack (+) into ON but the error is for WHERE clause.

Comment: The questions demonstrates the error being raised in the ON clause. That's not the problem though; the error _should_ be raised. The issue/bug is that it's not _always_ being raised as it is documented to be.